# dpkg is installing the wrong version of a package

Tags: 12.04, package-management, dpkg

I'm attempting to upgrade Graphicsmagick on Ubuntu 12.04 from 1.3.12 to 1.3.18 or newer. I tried to install it following [these instructions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/install-graphicsmagick-ppa-ubuntu-linux/), but Graphicsmagick did not upgrade and remained 1.3.12. I resorted to manually downloading the .deb and installing it using `dpkg`, but came across this behaviour, where `dpkg` would install the older version of the package.

```
$ gm
GraphicsMagick 1.3.12 2010-03-08 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
[...]
$ sudo apt-get remove graphicsmagick
[...]
$ gm
-bash: /usr/bin/gm: No such file or directory
$ wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/graphicsmagick/graphicsmagick_1.3.18-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i graphicsmagick_1.3.18-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package graphicsmagick.
(Reading database ... 493625 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking graphicsmagick (from graphicsmagick_1.3.18-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up graphicsmagick (1.3.18-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
$ gm
GraphicsMagick 1.3.12 2010-03-08 Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
```

The package does indeed contain the advertised version of graphicsmagick, as installing it on another machine worked fine. Is there some explanation for why a newer version of the package can't be installed? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, using neither `sudo apt-get purge` or `dpkg purge` solve the problem.

Comment: This is happening because your `libgraphicsmagick3` version is 1.3.12. Unfortunately you can't install 1.3.18 version of `libgraphicsmagick3` on 12.04 as it is available for 14.04 only.

Comment: Hmm. Is there no way then to get graphicsmagick 1.3.18 on Ubuntu 14.04 without doing something like compiling from source?

Comment: Can't say. Wait for some really good answer.

Comment: @RichardYe What is the output of `apt-cache policy libc6`?

Comment: `apt-cache policy libc6`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8413998/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to build version 1.3.20 from source.

Go to the URL ftp://ftp.graphicsmagick.org/pub/GraphicsMagick/GraphicsMagick-LATEST.tar.gz and download the file to your Downloads folder and when it asks for a username click cancel or just close the popup.

Then open a terminal and execute the following commands one-by-one:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install automake build-essential libtool linux-headers-generic
cd ~/Downloads    
tar zxvf GraphicsMagick-LATEST.tar.gz
cd GraphicsMagick-1.3.20
autoreconf -f -i
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

This will install version 1.3.20! If it does not work in the end, delete the extracted archive (GraphicsMagick-1.3.20 folder) and start over at command #3 on the list of commands above and when you run ./config, read the output and if there are missing dependencies, they should be listed somewhere in there.

Note: This may fail to run on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 because of outdated versions of `automake` and `autoreconf`. To resolve, change `AC_PREREQ` in `configure.ac` to `2.68` and change `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = 1.12` to `1.11` in Makefile.am before running `autoreconf`. The package doesn't need the newer dependencies and compiles just fine.

Comment: I added `linux-headers-generic` to the `sudo apt-get install` list also just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping to avoid having to build from source (it runs on itinerant servers which need to be set up each time, so building from source would take a while), but I suppose I could build it from source once and host the binary somewhere.

Comment: This will fail to run on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 because of outdated versions of `automake` and `autoreconf`. To resolve, change `AC_PREREQ` in `configure.ac` to `2.68` and change `AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = 1.12` to `1.11` in `Makefile.am`. The package doesn't need the newer dependencies and compiles just fine.